# Search by foreign key id in admin

Tags: django, search, django-admin, foreign-keys

I'm trying to achieve something apparently simple but I couldn't find any answer, neither on Google nor here. I have a Django model, something dead-simple:

```
class Shipment(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction)
```

I would like to be able to search in my Shipment Admin page by transaction.id. To clarity,
I want this (this code obviously doesn't work):

```
class ShipmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'transaction')
    search_fields = ['id', 'transaction.id']
```

This can't work cause transaction.id does not name a field. Any idea?
By "search" I mean be able to insert my transaction id inside the search box of the Shipment Admin page, press "search" and automatically retrieve appropriate transactions.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

as with the other admin options, you need to use [__ for foreign key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields)s e.g.

```
search_fields = ['id', 'transaction__id']
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work if you're going up two levels of foreign keys, i.e. 'allocation__project__name' doesn't work where allocation has an FK to project and project has a name.  How do you solve that? I keep getting the "<field> is not a callable, an attribute of <model>"

Comment: @radtek, that seems to work for me, I can do fk1__fk2__field, only tried in 1.7 tho, are allocation and project just ForeignKey()?

Comment: Yeah I know it should work, I even seen an example on django docs but for some reason it isn't working for me.  If I don't find a way around it I'll setup a sample repo with the conflicting code.

Comment: @radtek sorry late reply, strange, probably not, but have you tried removing all the other admin options, just to make sure its not misleading message?

Comment: @JamesO I'll see if I can isolate it and recreate the issue

Comment: You'll want to use the equals sign with something like `search_fields = ('=id',)`. Otherwise by default an `like` query will be done, so a query for `6` could also bring back results for `1556`. Not usually the intention.

Answer (score 10):

[search_fields documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields):

> You can also perform a related lookup on a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField with the lookup API "follow" notation

Solution:

```
search_fields = ['id', 'transaction__id']
```

Comment: For those getting a `Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains` error, check that you're actually using the related lookup `transaction__id` instead of the FK column name `transaction_id`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Id field which is the primary key in Django is a `BigIntergerField` right? That's numbers.

So in one of the model's field `transaction` table, You should set a `primary_key=True`.

Then when you reference it, you can enter the name of the foreign key instance.

Eg.

Table `Category` with one field 'name' is a foreign key in `post_category`:

I set the field 'name' to be its primary key.
So to reference it in searchfields,

I will type:

```
category__name
```

Doing this allows me to search by category.

You will need to delete your database and re_migrate unless it'd throw a database error because of the previously stored primary key.

If the answer above doesn't work for you, try this. It totally worked for me.

Comment: This does not add much on top of the existing answers, and hardly addresses the actual question.

Comment: Uhmm, I am confused though because I got exactly the same errors. I checked all over the net and couldn't find the solution.

Comment: I figured the answer by myself and thought it'd be nice to help others. How do you know it doesn't address the question. Faced something similar?